# create registry key, not the usual

Tags: c#, .net

Been googling but I cant find out how to create a registry key itself, not a subkey string value as is seen in all the tutorials. The registry is like a tree with branches and leaves, I want to create a new branch and add a leaf

```
|tree
|-branch
|  |-my branch
|-branch
```

Thanks for any help

More info to make it clearer as i'm being pointed to what I dont need ;)

you click on one of the registry keys, next to it is an arrow pointing down, you click it and you get more keys maybe with another arrow pointing down for more ketys, well thats what I'm trying to create a "folder" looking thing. I'm not sure how else I can explain but `CreateSubKey` does nothing like that for me:

```
Key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsof\game\addons\myaddons");
```

Now, when I check it there is no folder-like icon named `myaddons`

Comment: there's a typo in CreateSubKey ("Microsof" instead of "Microsoft") - might that be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but you may use `Registry.SetValue(string keyName, string valueName, object value, RegistryValueKind valuekind)` to create Keys/Subkeys and its values.

**Example**

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Picrofo Software\", "", ""); //Tree
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Picrofo Software\Subkey", "", ""); //Branch
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Picrofo Software\Subkey", "Value Name", "Value", RegistryValueKind.String); //Branch's value
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Picrofo Software\Another Subkey", "", ""); //Branch
```

This will create a key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\` with the name `Picrofo Software`. Then, creates a subkey in the key we've created with the name `Subkey` and sets a value of name `Value Name` and its value `Value` of type `String`. Finally, creates another subkey in `Picrofo Software` with the name `Another Subkey` which has no specific value.

[image: Example]

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [RegistryKey.CreateSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.createsubkey.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples of how to do this in the documentation for the RegistryKey class on MSDN. You basically create your "branch" as a subkey, and then call the same function against that object.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.WIN32.REGISTRY%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) and [RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.WIN32.REGISTRYKEY%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) classes should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You are always creating subkey, you can't create root key. You can choose in which top level key to add. I would advise you to add to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER and it is the best way

```
Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("myKey");//HKEY_CURRENT_USER
```

But you can add to other keys. If you want to add to the root key use:

```
Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("myKey");//HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
```

And if you want to add to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE use

```
Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("myKey");//HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

etc.

Comment: So then it's impossible in C# to create a new key (not a key with a value) because the key i want to append to is not in classesroot its in currentuser

Comment: I don't understand you question, the first line shows how to create subkey in CurentUser